# Akka Dead letters on Akka IO Actor

Tags: postgresql, io, debian, sbt, akka

First question here on StackOverflow!

Anyways, on to the topic at hand:

I have a Debian 8.0 (Jessie or Testing) installation. For some reason, I'm getting eve-central.com's API somehow funky because instead of grabbing posted data to it from another script on my server and putting it in PostgreSQL, it basically errors and continues to run, but doesn't import the data from the other script.

```
root@MN-VM-Host01:~/evec/core# sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /root/evec/core/project
[info] Set current project to eve-central-ng (in build file:/root/evec/core/)
[info] Running com.evecentral.Boot
22:27:25,422 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
22:27:25,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
22:27:25,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/root/evec/core/target/scala-2.10/classes/logback.xml]
22:27:25,501 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/root/evec/core/target/scala-2.10/classes/logback.xml]] every 60 seconds.
22:27:25,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
22:27:25,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
22:27:25,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
22:27:25,531 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
22:27:25,571 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
22:27:25,574 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
22:27:25,600 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:14 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy][maxHistory]]
22:27:25,606 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
22:27:25,608 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern logs/evec.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i for the active file
22:27:25,611 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'logs/evec.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i'.
22:27:25,611 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - Roll-over at midnight.
22:27:25,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - Setting initial period to Wed Mar 04 22:00:47 CST 2015
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Cleaning on start up
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.SizeAndTimeBasedArchiveRemover@296d1f3f - first clean up after appender initialization
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.SizeAndTimeBasedArchiveRemover@296d1f3f - periodsElapsed = 64
22:27:25,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
22:27:25,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: logs/evec.log
22:27:25,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [logs/evec.log]
22:27:25,627 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [cc.spray.can] to INFO
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
22:27:25,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1a936409 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
22:27:25,422 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
22:27:25,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
22:27:25,423 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/root/evec/core/target/scala-2.10/classes/logback.xml]
22:27:25,501 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/root/evec/core/target/scala-2.10/classes/logback.xml]] every 60 seconds.
22:27:25,501 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
22:27:25,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
22:27:25,506 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
22:27:25,531 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
22:27:25,571 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
22:27:25,574 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
22:27:25,600 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:14 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy][maxHistory]]
22:27:25,606 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
22:27:25,608 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern logs/evec.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i for the active file
22:27:25,611 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'logs/evec.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i'.
22:27:25,611 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - Roll-over at midnight.
22:27:25,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@6a158dc7 - Setting initial period to Wed Mar 04 22:00:47 CST 2015
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Cleaning on start up
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.SizeAndTimeBasedArchiveRemover@296d1f3f - first clean up after appender initialization
22:27:25,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.SizeAndTimeBasedArchiveRemover@296d1f3f - periodsElapsed = 64
22:27:25,625 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
22:27:25,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: logs/evec.log
22:27:25,626 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [logs/evec.log]
22:27:25,627 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [cc.spray.can] to INFO
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
22:27:25,628 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
22:27:25,630 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1a936409 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

[INFO] [03/04/2015 22:27:26.778] [evec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://evec/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to /0.0.0.0:80
[INFO] [03/04/2015 22:27:26.780] [evec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://evec/deadLetters] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Bound] from Actor[akka://evec/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0#417259830] to Actor[akka://evec/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am using SBT version 0.13.6 and i distinctly remember something like Akka Actors 2.3.5 breaking the entire thing... Is there a way in Debian 8 to revert to say, 2.1.4?

EDIT: Here are the contents of Boot.Scala (the file called by me executing the command "sbt run" in the labeled directory which is now at /evec/core/):

```
package com.evecentral

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import akka.routing.SmallestMailboxRouter
import akka.util.Timeout
import com.evecentral.api._
import com.evecentral.dataaccess._
import com.evecentral.datainput.{StatisticsCaptureActor, UnifiedUploadParsingActor, UploadStorageActor}
import com.evecentral.routes.RouteFinderActor
import com.evecentral.util.ActorNames
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import spray.can.Http
import spray.http.StatusCodes._
import spray.routing._
import spray.routing.Directives.{complete, requestUri}
import spray.util.LoggingContext

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Boot extends App {

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("evec")

  val systemsMap = StaticProvider.systemsMap
  val stationsMAp = StaticProvider.stationsMap
  val typesMap = StaticProvider.typesMap
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("boot")
  // initialize SLF4J early


  // "Singleton" actors
  log.info("Booting GetOrdersActor")
  val ordersActor = system.actorOf(Props[GetOrdersActor].withRouter(new SmallestMailboxRouter(10)), ActorNames.getorders)
  log.info("Booting GetHistStats")
  val gethiststats = system.actorOf(Props[GetHistStats], ActorNames.gethiststats)
  log.info("Booting StatisticsCaptureActor")
  val statCap = system.actorOf(Props[StatisticsCaptureActor], ActorNames.statCapture)
  log.info("Booting UploadStorageActor")
  val unifiedActor = system.actorOf(Props[UploadStorageActor].withRouter(new SmallestMailboxRouter(3)), ActorNames.uploadstorage)
  log.info("Booting RouteActor")
  val routeActor = system.actorOf(Props[RouteFinderActor], ActorNames.routefinder)
  log.info("Booting OrderCacheActor")
  val statCache = system.actorOf(Props[OrderCacheActor], ActorNames.statCache)
  log.info("Booting UnifiedUploadParsingActor")
  val parser = system.actorOf(Props[UnifiedUploadParsingActor].withRouter(new SmallestMailboxRouter(10)), ActorNames.unifiedparser)

  def catchAllHandler() =
    ExceptionHandler {
      case e: Exception =>
        requestUri { uri =>
          log.error("Exception at URI " + uri, e)
          complete(InternalServerError, "An internal error occurred. Here is a debugging stacktrace. \n" +
            "Please report issues to https://github.com/theatrus/eve-central.com\n\n" + e.getStackTraceString)
        }
    }


  class APIServiceActor extends Actor with APIv2Service with APIv3Service {
    def actorRefFactory = context
    implicit val route = RoutingSettings.default
    implicit val exception = ExceptionHandler.default
    def receive = runRoute(handleExceptions(catchAllHandler()) { v2Service ~ api3Service })

    override implicit val timeout: Timeout = 60.seconds
  }
  log.info("Booting APIServiceActor")
  val apiModule = system.actorOf(Props[APIServiceActor].withRouter(new SmallestMailboxRouter(10)), ActorNames.http_apiv3)

  IO(Http)(system) ! Http.Bind(apiModule, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)

}
```

Comment: Let me know if you guys need any more information and I will edit it in.

Comment: It's not clear how this is programming related.  Where is the code you need help with?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Been busy with other stuff regarding work. I will edit in the code for Boot.Scala (the file giving me the issues in this other guy's builds of software) shortly.